# How can I fix a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" in my Python solution for finding maximum index difference?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, syntax-error

I'm attempting to solve a problem where I need to find the maximum index difference in an array while adhering to certain constraints.
I wrote the code in java and tried to replicate it in Python.
However, when implementing my solution in Python, I encountered a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" related to the logical AND operator.

I'm expecting the code to iterate through the array elements and update the maximum index difference according to the given constraints.

```
class Solution:
def maxIndexDiff(self, a, n): 
    right = []
    right[n-1] = a[n-1]
    for i in range(n-2, 0, -1):
        right[i] = max(a[i], right[i+1])
    i, j = 0, 0
    ans = 0
    while(i < n && j < n):  # SyntaxError occurs here
        if(a[i] <= right[j]):
            ans = max(ans, j, -1)
            j += 1
        else:
            i += 1
    return ans
```

Comment: Logical AND is `and`. [Boolean operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

Comment: As mentioned by @s3dev the logical and in python is the key word and not &&